# MySQL Totals By Year Column and Months

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Looking for suggestions on how to best pull some data. I need to do some calcs but pull the data by year and month to make a table like such. If there's a way to have the years be auto generated by the range, all the better.

```
        2012    2013    2014
Jan     $243    $567    $890
Feb     $123    $456    $908
Mar     ...       ...
Apr
May
```

I can get the data to be ordered by year, month but as you know that is not easily conducive to putting it into an HTML table without some middle ware storing and iterating through found sets.

I've used the following query which is close but not exact.

```
select year(date_donated) as year, monthname(date_donated) as month, sum(amount_donated) as total_donations, count(date_donated) as count_donations from my_donations where (date_donated between "2012-01-01" and "2014-12-31") group by year(date_donated), month(date_donated) order by field(month, 'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December')
```

Comment: You are describing a pivot table. This is non trivial in MySQL and often better to do in whatever is producing your HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is much easier to do this in your client side.

But if for some reason you still want to pivot your data on the database side you can leverage dynamic SQL.

If you want to have years and months continuous regardless of the data you'll also need some sort of tally (numbers) table. E.g. like this one

```sql
CREATE VIEW tally AS
  SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11;
```

Now the dynamic SQL part:

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date_donated) = ', year_start + n, ' THEN amount_donated END) `', year_start + n, '`'))
  INTO @sql
  FROM tally CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2012 year_start, 2014 year_end) y
 WHERE n <= year_end - year_start 
 ORDER BY n;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MONTHNAME(''2000-01-01'' + INTERVAL n MONTH) month,', @sql,
' FROM tally t LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT date_donated, amount_donated
     FROM my_donations
    WHERE date_donated BETWEEN ''', 2012, '-01-01'' AND ''', 2014, '-12-31'' 
) d
  ON t.n + 1 = MONTH(date_donated)                
GROUP BY t.n 
ORDER BY t.n');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|     MONTH |   2012 |   2013 |   2014 |
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|
|   January |    243 |    567 |    890 |
|  February |    123 |    456 |    908 |
|     March | (null) | (null) | (null) |
...
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95b8b/10)** demo

Comment: @jquery-junkie Did it help  in any way?